# How to publish python toolbox with lots of tools in ArcGIS Server 10.3?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, geoprocessing-service, python-toolbox

I have python toolbox with like 40 tools and I need a quick way to publish the whole toolbox. I found some instructions in the documentation, they state that every tool should be executed and their results should be published by using ArcMap/ArcCatalog, but this will take forever!!! Because some tools accept maps in JSON, have a lot of complex parameters, needs extremely accurate parameters to execute succesfully, etc!

Is there a new simple way to publish the whole toolbox?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f43d5857256946a9a35dd87b55c663f0 ?

Comment: Hi Branco, thanks for the suggestion, but this "auto publishing" approach also executes the tools, and they also need preprogrammed and correct parameters. So it wont help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can only publish a tool once it has been successfully run.

See this (older) thread with ESRI's reasoning for imposing this restriction: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/54637